# using automated code not executing correctly

Tags: python

I am needing a code to buy when 10 ema crosses over the 20 and 50 and sell when the 10 crosses under the 20 and 50.

The issues im having is with this code;

```
  // Definition of code parameters
DEFPARAM CumulateOrders = False // Cumulating positions deactivated

// Conditions to enter long positions
indicator1 = ExponentialAverage[10](close)
indicator2 = ExponentialAverage[20](close)
c1 = (indicator1 CROSSES OVER indicator2 and  )
  indicator3 = ExponentialAverage[10](close)
indicator4 = ExponentialAverage[50](close)
c2 = (indicator3 CROSSES OVER indicator4)

IF c1 and c2 THEN
BUY 10 CONTRACT AT MARKET
ENDIF

// Conditions to exit long positions
indicator5 = ExponentialAverage[10](close)
indicator6 = ExponentialAverage[20](close)
c3 = (indicator5 CROSSES UNDER indicator6)
indicator7 = ExponentialAverage[10](close)
indicator8 = ExponentialAverage[50](close)
c4 = (indicator7 CROSSES UNDER indicator8)

IF c3 AND c4 THEN
SELL AT MARKET
ENDIF
```

It is only buying when the 10 20 50 cross exactly at the same time. I do not want that, what i need is it to buy when it crosses both not necessarily at the same time. and the selling side the opposite.

Thank you

Comment: Does not look like [python] question.

Comment: you should probably ask this here: https://www.prorealcode.com/forum/prorealtime-english-forum/proorder-support/